# Access denied during geopandas read parquet from s3 bucket

Tags: pandas, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, geopandas

After moving the parquet file containing the locally created geodataframe to s3, I tried to read the file within AWS Glue as follows.

```
import geopandas as gpd
test_gdf = gpd.read_parquet("s3://bucket_name/key/file.parquet")
```

However, OS Error occurred as follows

```
OSError: When getting information for key 'key/file.parquet' in bucket 'bucket_name': AWS Error ACCESS_DENIED during HeadObject operation: No response body.
```

What I found strange was that when I run pandas.read_parquet, it runs successfully.

```
import pandas as pd
test_gdf = pd.read_parquet("s3://bucket_name/key/file.parquet")
```

However, I confirmed that reading a geodataframe by pandas and then converting it back to geodataframe takes a lot of time.

Therefore, I want to read the parquet file directly through geopandas.

Referring to other questions, there were issues with IAM Role or s3 bucket policy, so I checked them.

Policy at AWS Glue Role

```
{
...
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
...
}
```

S3 Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForDatalakeBucket",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "denyInsecureTransport",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                },
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:iam::IAM_USER:role/GLUE_ROLE"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::IAM_USER:role/GLUE_ROLE",
                    "arn:aws:iam::IAM_USER:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What needs to be resolved so that geopandas can successfully read parquet files from s3?

Comment: How are you providing ACCESS credentials to your python script? via IAM user or IAM role? If user how do you provide creds? Can you also confirm if s3://bucket_name/key/file.parquet is a file or a directory?

Comment: I used AWS Glue jupyter notebook, and the notebook has a IAM policy of the IAM role that allows all actions to all buckets. And If I read the data by `pandas`, I can load the datas from s3 bucket. However, if i tried to read by `geopandas`, the access denied error would occur.

Comment: Can you add the full python script by sanitising it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is like below,

```py
import fsspec
import geopandas as gpd

with fsspec.open(feather_file) as f
  gdf = gpd.read_feather(f)
```

If you want to access feather file in s3 bucket, you need to open the file by fsspec and try to read file by geopandas.read_feather.

You can find more reference in https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html